# Call JavaScript from window to another in Adobe AIR

Tags: javascript, air

In my Adobe AIR application I hide the initial window and create another window that loads in a separate HTML file. Is it possible to call a function in one window that exists inside another?

I have read examples such as: [Possible to call a Javascript method in the context of another window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180121/possible-to-call-a-javascript-method-in-the-context-of-another-window)

But I'm using Native Windows and not HTML Windows so don't think it'll work.

Any ideas?

The structure would be like:

```
`file1.html`

function doSomething() {


}
```

So I want to call the doSomething function inside file1 from file2

```
`file2.html`

doSomething();
```

Comment: you would need to use an AIR command to do so, if one exists.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Maybe LocalConnection http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html might help, you can comunicate within AS3 Object and they would communicate with Javascript in their way http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=3996