# How to call a function from outside the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I call a function that is declared on my parent window?
I have a new window that opened through calling window.open, and the content of the new window is a grid, each item in grid has link/anchor. I want in my onclick event of each item is to call a function that declared on my parent html. How can I acheive this?
Below is my sample code.

```
function showCustomWindow(filter){

    var title = '';
         source = behindDueDates;
         title = 'Client Actions Behind Due Dates';

    var htmlContent = '<div id="content"><h2> '+ title +'</h2><table class="table" id="behindActions">';
        htmlContent +='<thead class="thead-inverse">';
        htmlContent += '<tr class="tableHeader">';
        htmlContent += '<td> Subject </td>';
        htmlContent += '<td> Regarding </td>';
        htmlContent += '</tr>';
        htmlContent += '</thead>';
        htmlContent += '<tbody>';

        $.each(source, function(key, value){
                var regarding = value.attributes.regardingobjectid;

                htmlContent += '<tr>';
                htmlContent += '<td data-id="'+value.Id+'"><a href="#" onclick="redirectToRecord("'+value.Id + "entity"+ value.attributes.activitytypecode.formattedValue +'")">' + value.getValue("subject") + '</a></td>';
                htmlContent += '<td>' + regarding + '</td>';
                htmlContent += '</tr>';
        })                

        htmlContent += '</tbody>';
        htmlContent += '</table></div>';

    var win = window.open("", title, "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=1000,height=800");
        win.moveTo(10, 10);
        win.document.write('<html><head><title> ' + title + ' </title></head><body>');
        win.document.write(htmlContent);
        win.document.write('</body></html>');

}
function redirectToRecord(value){
   alert("Event to call from second window")
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read http://www.tonybhimani.com/2011/10/16/javascript-controlling-a-popup-windows-parent-window/ ?

Comment: Already got it working, my workaround is to add an EventListener to the new window. e.g win.addEventLister('click',function(value){redirectToRecord(value)},true)

Answer (score 1):

parent should refer to the opening window.

`parent.method()` will call a method. It has to be on the same domain though, no cross domain calls will work.

Answer (score 1):

Call parent window function with windiw.opener helper:

```
if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
    window.opener.function_in_parent(); //Parent window function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the child window in this way:

```
var w = window.open("/uri", "title");
w.childFunction();
```

and parent:

```
<a onclick="parent.anyname();" href="#" > Click me </a>
```

Or try this approach: [Possible to call a Javascript method in the context of another window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180121/possible-to-call-a-javascript-method-in-the-context-of-another-window)