# Pass variables through to new window and send AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to open a new window on a click event, pass some variables through and when the page has loaded run an ajax request to display data.

So far I have tried it like this, I am unable to manipulate the new window.

I want the jQuery file to manipulate the new window directly.

**My current code**

```
function displayDrillData(errorVal, agencyID, ruleName) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax/getDrillData.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
          errorVal: errorVal,
          agencyID: agencyID,
          ruleName: ruleName
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var win = window.open("../cannedData.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
        },
        complete: function(data) {

        },
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click','.countDrill', function(){
        var errorVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('.errorVal').text();
        var ruleName = $(this).closest('tr').parents('tbody').attr('class');
        displayDrillData(errorVal, agencyID, ruleName);
      })
    });
```

When the window has been opened I'd like the displayDrillData() to be fired, so I can directly manipulate the DOM and display whatever data has been returned.

I need the variables in data to be passed through also at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure about that helps you but I think you can use queryString? Have you tried?

Comment: If you want to be able to call displayDrillData from the new window, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180121/possible-to-call-a-javascript-method-in-the-context-of-another-window .

Comment: @fabio.sussetto How can I access elements in the window? If there is an input how do I put a value into that input? I tried `this.window.document.$('input').val('test');`